Can black and white cooperatively put a stalemate to black in 16 moves (under ser-h conditions)?


ser-h=n – serial helpstalemate in n moves. Black execute n moves in a row, after that White execute a stalemate for bK.
Additional questions:

a) how many stalemates are possible under the same conditions, but in 17 moves (how many squares will the black king be on?)

b) bonus question. Why is there an f5 pawn in the diagram?


I wrote this task myself. Good luck finding a solution! You'll need it...
P.S.
In fact, the task, of course, has nothing to do with chess as a game. From chess, there are only rules for the movement of pieces. The task is purely mathematical. On the logistics of movement.

In general, to solve the problem, you must first come up with a stalemate position, realizing that only one white piece will be able to make a move (some of the white pieces may disappear from the board). This dramatically narrows the room for maneuver.
